# Repository + factory pattern implementation for classes with multiple inheritance in PHP?

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture, repository-pattern, factory-pattern

Here is the case: let's say I have a `User` abstract class. This class is extended into `Employee` and `Customer` subclasses.

The `User` class has basic attributes like `name` and `address`. `Employee` has an additional attribute `sallary`. `Customer` has an additional attribute `membership_code`.

These entities are stored in multiple tables: `users`, `employees`, and `customers`. The `users` table contains basic information about any user. The `employees` and `customers` table refer to the `users` table, and in each contains the additional attributes.

`users` table:

```
id | name       | address           | type
---+------------+-------------------+---------
1  | Employee 1 | First Address St. | Employee
2  | Customer 1 | First Address St. | Customer
```

`employees` table:

```
user_id | salary
--------+---------
1       | 5000
```

`customers` table:

```
user_id | membership_code
--------+---------
2       | 1325_5523_2351
```

Here is what I have in mind as to how these should be implemented in PHP:

```php
abstract class User
{
    protected $id;
    protected $name;

    public static function load(int $id): User
    {
        /** @var array $data */
        $data = get_a_row_from_users_table_by($id); // this part does a query to DB

        return new $data['type']($data['id'], $data['name']);
    }

    final public function __construct($id, $name)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->init();
    }

    abstract protected function init();
}

class Employee extends User
{
    protected $salary;

    protected function init()
    {
        /** @var array $data */
        $data = get_a_row_from_employees_table_by($this->id); // this part does a query to DB
        $this->salary = $data['salary'];
    }
}

class Customer extends User
{
    protected $membership_code;

    protected function init()
    {
        /** @var array $data */
        $data = get_a_row_from_customers_table_by($this->id); // this part does a query to DB
        $this->salary = $data['membership_code'];
    }
}
```

Here is how it would look like in the controller:

```php
$employee = User::load(1); // return Employee type
$customer= User::load(2); // return Customer type
```

However, I feel like the code above still seems a bit hacky to maintain. Recently I read a book discussing about *domain-driven design* and how the persistence mechanism should be separated into a **Repository**. On the other hand, I also discovered that the type-switching mechanism, for example between `Employee` and `Customer`, should be done in a **Factory**.

I have a bit of a grasp to the concepts of **Repository** and **Factory**, but I still failed to understand how to combine and implement those concepts into a working code.

In this case, how should the above be implemented to use **Repository** and **Factory** pattern in PHP?

Comment: If you want to use the repository pattern or the enterprise architecture in your project; there are some ORM libraries designed to work like that. Maybe you can check the doctrine PHP library(https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/getting-started.html). It doesn't make a lot of sense to use repository pattern with an Active Record implementation. The power of active record is to be able to access your database entities and relations wherever you need them They already include the repository. If you do that, your repositories will be repository repositories.

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN well, it can be done, but I don't want to be too dependent to some libraries. I try to look at this problem on the architectural basis -- to figure out how I could design a simple case like said in a native PHP way. As far as I understand it, the benefit of using the Repository pattern is that the domain logic is seperated from data persistence logic, so that it can later be easily replaced with any ORM of choice without too much refactoring of the domain code.

Comment: What you are mentioning here is really good practice. However, I think we need a scope. As creators; we have to solve the problems actually exist. And we shouldn't try to fix problems we guess will occur in the unknown future. E.g.: If you are creating a library that will support both doctrine and eloquent; it is great to have the repository pattern for your services. So that you can switch between easily. But if we're talking about an enterprise project; believe me you won't change your ORM. Repository Pattern will still be beneficial to have an architecture and easily collaborate.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach for creating an `User` abstract base class is good. Your table structure also looks good.

Keep in mind that your entities (such as `User`) should not have dependency on infrastructure, the reason is that including the infrastructure into your entity pulls you away from SRP... in the example above your `User` entity is doing too much work... the logic for reading and writing to DB should be pulled out of the entity... they belong to `UserRepository`

Your assumption about putting the persistence mechanism into a Repository is correct. You can implement a generic `UserRepository` which returns `Employee` and `Customer`... how you want to implement the generic repository is your choice, but regardless, the persistence logic does not belong to `User` Entity.